# Quicksort using the second element as a pivot (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I want to implement Quicksort in Prolog using the second element of the list as a pivot but I'm not sure how I can go about doing it. I was told that I can represent the input list into pairs: [First | [Pivot | Tail]] but I'm not sure how I can use this to help me. I'm new to Prolog so any hints would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
This is the code I have written for Quicksort that uses the first element as the pivot:

```
qsort([],[]):- !.
qsort([Pivot|Tail],Sorted):-
        split(Pivot,Tail,Less,Greater),
        qsort(Less,SortedLess),
        qsort(Greater,SortedGreater),
        append(SortedLess,[Pivot|SortedGreater],Sorted).
split(_,[],[],[]).
split(Pivot,[X|T],[X|Less],Greater):-
        X=<Pivot,split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
split(Pivot,[X|T],Less,[X|Greater]):-
        X>Pivot,split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
```

Comment: take `Pivot` out of `[Pivot | Tail]`, and get `Tail`.  take `Pivot` out of `[First | [Pivot | Tail]]`, and get `[First | Tail]`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I really understand what you mean

Comment: well then it means you need to read some tutorials or take a course. cheers,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog Quicksort using second element as a pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227028/prolog-quicksort-using-second-element-as-a-pivot)