# In prolog, how to write Quicksort is use second element as pivot?

Tags: prolog, quicksort

In my example, I have done to use the first (left-most) element of the given list is selected as the pivot.

```
qsort([],[]):- !.
qsort([Pivot|Tail],Sorted):-
        split(Pivot,Tail,Less,Greater),
        qsort(Less,SortedLess),
        qsort(Greater,SortedGreater),
        append(SortedLess,[Pivot|SortedGreater],Sorted).
split(_,[],[],[]).
split(Pivot,[X|T],[X|Less],Greater):-
        X=<Pivot,split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
split(Pivot,[X|T],Less,[X|Greater]):-
        X>Pivot,split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
```

However, I am wondering how to use the second element as pivot

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122409/quicksort-using-the-second-element-as-a-pivot-prolog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog Quicksort using second element as a pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227028/prolog-quicksort-using-second-element-as-a-pivot)

Comment: @joel76 there's now another entry, with an answer, that we can close this one as a duplicate of. (and the one you proposed, as well).