# Prolog Quicksort using second element as a pivot

Tags: prolog, pivot, quicksort

I've been trying to learn prolog and I want to use the second element of a list as the pivot of a quicksort.

I thought using [Head | [Pivot | Tail] ] as the input in the method would work, but then I was not sure where I could place "Head", the first element.

like this:

```
qsort([],[]):- !.
qsort([Head|[Pivot|Tail]],Sorted):-
        split(Pivot,[Head|Tail],Less,Greater),
        qsort(Less,SortedLess),
        qsort(Greater,SortedGreater),
        append(SortedLess,[Pivot|SortedGreater],Sorted).
split(_,[],[],[]).
split(Pivot,[X|T],[X|Less],Greater):-
        X=<Pivot,split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
split(Pivot,[X|T],Less,[X|Greater]):-
        X>Pivot,split(Pivot,T,Less,Greater).
```

However, when I try to sort the list with `qsort([8, 3, 4, 12, 25, 4, 6, 1, 9, 22, 6], Sorted).` It simply returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not take into account sorting a list with *one* element. That list will not match with `[Head|[Pivot|Tail]]`.

Answer (score 3):

> However, when I try to sort the list with `qsort([8, 3, 4, 12, 25, 4, 6, 1, 9, 22, 6], Sorted)`. It simply returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Eventually this algorithm will make calls with a list with *exactly one* element, and you did not define a `qsort/2` clause that will match with that list.

You can resolve this by adding a rule:

```
qsort([],[]).
qsort([X], [X]).
qsort([Head, Pivot|Tail],Sorted):-
        split(Pivot,[Head|Tail],Less,Greater),
        qsort(Less,SortedLess),
        qsort(Greater,SortedGreater),
        append(SortedLess,[Pivot|SortedGreater],Sorted).
```

This gives us:

```
?- qsort([8, 3, 4, 12, 25, 4, 6, 1, 9, 22, 6], Sorted).
Sorted = [1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9, 12|...] ;
false.
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! This is my first question on this website; you guys are incredibly helpful!